# SwipeCellKit not swiping

Tags: ios, swift

I can't get my cells to swipe using SwipeCellKit. The code is below and I suspect it is the cell.delegate row, however I seem to be blind to the problem. I am assuming it will be immediately obvious to someone else.

Note: CharacterTableViewCell is a SwipeTableViewCell class.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self as? SwipeTableViewCellDelegate

    if let char = chars?[indexPath.row] {

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

        formattedString
            .normal("\(char.charName) - iLevel: ")
            .bold("\(char.averageItemLevelEquipped)")
            .normal("\n\(classConverter(class: (char.charClass))) - \(char.spec) (\(char.role))\nMissing gems: \(char.emptySockets)\nEnchants: \(char.backEnchant)")

        cell.characterDataLabel.attributedText = formattedString

        cell.characterThumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.characterThumbnail.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.characterThumbnail.downloadedFrom(link: "http://render-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/character/\(char.thumbnail)")

        cell.characterBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: classColor(class: char.charClass))

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: print `cell.delegate` and check if it has any value

Comment: Might be a silly question, but what do you mean by print? In debug console?

Comment: Just add `print(cell.delegate)` after `cell.delegate = self as? SwipeTableViewCellDelegate` and check what you are getting in console.

Comment: I get 'nil' on every cell.

Comment: That means delegates is not assigning to cell. Can you share demo project?

Comment: Sure, it is here: https://github.com/Aecasorg/WoWilvlChecker Unless you meant something else...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174477/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-aecasorg).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dharmesh Kheni and the answers from [Delegate Method to UItableViewCell Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079135/delegate-method-to-uitableviewcell-swift) I worked out the issue.

Instead of having `cell.delegate = self as? SwipeTableViewCellDelegate` I moved the `SwipeTableViewCellDelegate` up to

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
```

That solved it. I knew it was an obvious answer! ;)