# control the content of UITableView cell from another cell with 2 classes / delegates Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, swift-protocols

I have a tableview that loads with three custom cells, a post header cell, a post image cell, and a post action cell. [see tableview cells here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7IoQ.png)

I currently have the playbutton for my videos in the postImage cell and it's working fine, however, I would like to move the functionality of the play button to the postAction cell where the user is voting yes or no, so when the user votes, it will also call the play video function (handlePlay).

New: I have PostActionCell as a custom class, and my home viewcontroller (HomeVC) as a delegate to handle the voting functionality.

I also have PostImageCell as a custom class, and I have tried to make HomeVC a delegate, when I do that I can access the tableview data I need, but then I get stuck trying to access the PostImageCell and PostActionCell in the same location.

I also tried making PostActionCell a delegate of PostImageCell and that allows me to access the PostImageCell class data that I need, but not the tableview data...

So, how/where should I be trying to access both custom classes?

Here is my Protocol for the PostImageCell:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol PostImageCellDelegate: class {
   func playVideo(_ cell: PostImageCell)
}

class PostImageCell: UITableViewCell {

   weak var delegate: PostImageCellDelegate?

   @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
   }

   func playVideoCalled() {
       delegate?.playVideo(self)
   }

   func prepareForReuse(layer: AVPlayerLayer) {
      super.prepareForReuse()
      layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
   }
}
```

Here is my attempt to access both my PostActionCell and PostImageCell on my HomeVC, but I can't seem to access the PostImageCell when I need it...:

```
//MARK: - PostActionCell and PostImageCell DELEGATE

extension HomeVC: PostActionCellDelegate, PostImageCellDelegate {

   func playVideo(_ cell: PostImageCell) {

      guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

      handlePlay2(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

   }

   func didTapVoteYesButton(_ voteButton: UIButton, on cell: PostActionCell ) {

      //playVideo( NEED PostImageCell HERE )

      guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

      voteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

      let post = posts[indexPath.section]

      VoteFirebase.setDidVoteYes(!post.didVote, for: post) { (success) in
         defer {
            voteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         }

         guard success else { return }

         post.yesCount += !post.didVote ? 1 : -1
         post.voteCount += !post.didVote ? 1 : -1
         post.didVote = !post.didVote

         guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PostActionCell
            else { return }

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.configureCell(cell, with: post)
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a job for delegates. Use the data source as a communication layer between the two cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delegate Method to UItableViewCell Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079135/delegate-method-to-uitableviewcell-swift)

Comment: You can register a callback with your PostActionCell. when user votes just call the callback handler block and inside that block call the handlePlay method.

Comment: @TamásSengel Thanks for the link to that question, I've been working through it. I'm stuck on how to "use the data source as a communication layer between the two cells" could you take a look at the updated question? Thanks!

Comment: @TamásSengel followup on that, in my code above, should I make my HomeVC extension also conform to my PostImageCell protocol, and try to access my PostImageCell that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the table view with this extension:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return next as? UITableView
    }
}
```

and you can access cell's indexPath with this extension:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

So you can calculate the player cell index and access it with `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`.

Comment: thanks, I am using that, I'm just not sure how to use that and combine with the other cell data that I need. I can access either tableview data and one cell data, or both cells, but not both cells and tableview data.. any advice?

Comment: In cell class:
- self.tableView -> access to tableView
- self.indexPath -> access to indexPath
so you have all needs for access any cell related to that cell. For example previous cell:

`guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return assertionFailure("This cell is not in tableView") }`
        `let priviousIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: indexPath.row-1, section: indexPath.section)`
        `guard let priviousIndexPathCell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return assertionFailure("Player cell not found") }`

Comment: This was what I needed, thank you! I wasn't aware that you could access the different cells by manipulating the IndexPath, that was very helpful. Thanks again!